# C++ USB conencted barcode scanner input capture

Tags: c++, qt, input, io, barcode

I have a USB connected barcode scanner.
When I scan a barcode it emulates a regular keyboard and prints the value of the code into the current window. I'm looking for a way to grab that output and not allow other applications to use it. Is it possible to somehow listen a particular USB port, grab the content and not outputting it to any other window, in such a way that the keyboard would still work fine?

I'm searching for a solution for C++. The current application works in a way that it grabs ALL the input from the keyboard (SetWindowsHookEx with WH_KEYBOARD_LL) but I need it only to grab it from a port.

All answers are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Some USB barcode scanners have an option to simulate sending to a serial port, see if yours does that.

Comment: What is the bar code scanner make/model? You need to put it in a mode that is not keyboard wedge/emulation mode. Most scanners support that with some configuration required.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't respond earlier.
The scanners we're using are mostly generic, but for the sake of the example we can use the one I am testing with: "Focus First Flash MS1690".

Thank you guys, I'll look into it in a couple of days and let you know where that gets me.